# Problem debugging in `gud-mode' (M-x `gdb' with `many-windows' enabled)

Tags: python, debugging, c++, gdb, gud

I'm debugging a large codebase (written in C++).
Everything works perfectly if I run gdb from a regular terminal as follows:

```
$ gdb <program-name>
Reading symbols from <program-name>...done.
$ (gdb) start <arg1> <arg2> <arg3>
...
...
... (everything running smoothly)
$ (gdb) quit
$
```

But when I run it in Emacs `gud-mode` (with `many-windows` enabled) it acts all screwy like so:

<kbd>M-x</kbd> `gdb`
`Run gdb (like this): gdb -q -i=mi <program-name>`

```
Current directory is ~/
Reading symbols from <program-name>...done.
(gdb) start <arg1> <arg2> <arg3>
Temporary breakpoint 1 at 0x4c04e9: file <path-to-executable>, line <x>.
Starting program: <path-to-executable> <arg1> <arg2> <arg3>
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".

Temporary breakpoint 1, main (argc=<x>, argv=0x7fffffffe518) at <path-to-executable>/main.cpp:<x>
<x>       <arbitrary-function>;
(gdb) Python Exception <class 'TypeError'> expected string or bytes-like object: 
Python Exception <class 'TypeError'> expected string or bytes-like object:
```

I don't get why this `Python Exception' is popping up (and continues popping up):

```
Python Exception <class 'TypeError'> expected string or bytes-like object: 
Python Exception <class 'TypeError'> expected string or bytes-like object:
```

---

**EDIT:**
**~24 hours/2 comments later**

`.bashrc`

```
# ~/.bashrc: executed by bash(1) for non-login shells.
# see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files (in the package bash-doc)
# for examples

# If not running interactively, don't do anything
case $- in
    *i*) ;;
      *) return;;
esac

# don't put duplicate lines or lines starting with space in the history.
# See bash(1) for more options
HISTCONTROL=ignoreboth

# append to the history file, don't overwrite it
shopt -s histappend

# for setting history length see HISTSIZE and HISTFILESIZE in bash(1)
HISTSIZE=1000
HISTFILESIZE=2000

# check the window size after each command and, if necessary,
# update the values of LINES and COLUMNS.
shopt -s checkwinsize

# If set, the pattern "**" used in a pathname expansion context will
# match all files and zero or more directories and subdirectories.
#shopt -s globstar

# make less more friendly for non-text input files, see lesspipe(1)
[ -x /usr/bin/lesspipe ] && eval "$(SHELL=/bin/sh lesspipe)"

# set variable identifying the chroot you work in (used in the prompt below)
if [ -z "${debian_chroot:-}" ] && [ -r /etc/debian_chroot ]; then
    debian_chroot=$(cat /etc/debian_chroot)
fi

# set a fancy prompt (non-color, unless we know we "want" color)
case "$TERM" in
    xterm-color|*-256color) color_prompt=yes;;
esac

# uncomment for a colored prompt, if the terminal has the capability; turned
# off by default to not distract the user: the focus in a terminal window
# should be on the output of commands, not on the prompt
#force_color_prompt=yes

if [ -n "$force_color_prompt" ]; then
    if [ -x /usr/bin/tput ] && tput setaf 1 >&/dev/null; then
    # We have color support; assume it's compliant with Ecma-48
    # (ISO/IEC-6429). (Lack of such support is extremely rare, and such
    # a case would tend to support setf rather than setaf.)
    color_prompt=yes
    else
    color_prompt=
    fi
fi

if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
else
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '
fi
unset color_prompt force_color_prompt

# If this is an xterm set the title to user@host:dir
case "$TERM" in
xterm*|rxvt*)
    PS1="\[\e]0;${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h: \w\a\]$PS1"
    ;;
*)
    ;;
esac

# enable color support of ls and also add handy aliases
if [ -x /usr/bin/dircolors ]; then
    test -r ~/.dircolors && eval "$(dircolors -b ~/.dircolors)" || eval "$(dircolors -b)"
    alias ls='ls --color=auto'
    #alias dir='dir --color=auto'
    #alias vdir='vdir --color=auto'

    alias grep='grep --color=auto'
    alias fgrep='fgrep --color=auto'
    alias egrep='egrep --color=auto'
fi

# colored GCC warnings and errors
#export GCC_COLORS='error=01;31:warning=01;35:note=01;36:caret=01;32:locus=01:quote=01'

# some more ls aliases
alias ll='ls -alF'
alias la='ls -A'
alias l='ls -CF'

# Add an "alert" alias for long running commands.  Use like so:
#   sleep 10; alert
alias alert='notify-send --urgency=low -i "$([ $? = 0 ] && echo terminal || echo error)" "$(history|tail -n1|sed -e '\''s/^\s*[0-9]\+\s*//;s/[;&|]\s*alert$//'\'')"'

# Alias definitions.
# You may want to put all your additions into a separate file like
# ~/.bash_aliases, instead of adding them here directly.
# See /usr/share/doc/bash-doc/examples in the bash-doc package.

if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
    . ~/.bash_aliases
fi

# enable programmable completion features (you don't need to enable
# this, if it's already enabled in /etc/bash.bashrc and /etc/profile
# sources /etc/bash.bashrc).
if ! shopt -oq posix; then
  if [ -f /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion ]; then
    . /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion
  elif [ -f /etc/bash_completion ]; then
    . /etc/bash_completion
  fi
fi
```

Comment: I also have problems with `gdb-many-windows` sometimes (not the same effect as you though) and a Google search showed me that I'm not the only one. There seems to be a race condition that only manifests in the many-windows mode and I haven't found a solution..

Comment: Is it possible that you have multiple versions of Python installed and that you have one somehow selected in your `.bashrc` or something like that? It seems like some sort of `gdb` plugin problem, and they are written in Python.

Comment: @wvxvw I just update the question including my `.bashrc` file. I couldn't find any instances of any python settings anywhere in the file. Let me know if you need any more information.

Comment: @Gilles Could you elaborate more this race condition? Maybe I can look into it more and figure something out.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by upgrading to `gdb-8.2`.